# When upgrading Angular 6to 8, I get incompatible peer dependency (using ng update @angular/core)

Tags: angular6, angular8

I'm using  this command `ng update @angular/cli @angular/corefor` to update angular version from 6 to 8 but it showing this bellow problem.

```
Package "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=7.0.0-rc.0 <8.0.0||>=6.0.0-rc.0 <7.0.0", would install "8.2.5").
Package "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires ">=7.0.0-rc.0 <8.0.0||>=6.0.0-rc.0 <7.0.0", would install "8.2.5").
Package "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-server" (requires ">=7.0.0-rc.0 <8.0.0||>=6.0.0-rc.0 <7.0.0", would install "8.2.5").
```

Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, check the dependencies one by one from the last one and use bellow code fore example :

> npm uninstall @angular/http

And again use:

> ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

Now you have to check what is your dependencies then one by one remove and after all, you will see your code will be updated.

then from last dependencies, you have to install your new version of your dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

When upgrading from Angular 8.2 to 10, I received a similar error. Running:

```
npm uninstall @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader
```

and then ng update worked for me.

Comment: it worked when I wanted to upgrade from Angular 9.0 to 10. Thank you